# What happens to applications if I sign in with a different account

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

My brother gave me his iPhone and I downloaded a bunch of non-free apps he purchased. Now I want to create a new account for me and sign in with it. What will happen to non-free applications I have downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Those apps will still work while they remain installed on the phone, but you will need to sign in to your brother's account to download updates for them, or to redownload them.